# Hangouts chats api script BOT to get user's location GPS coordinates

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, bots, google-hangouts, hangouts-api

We have developed a hangouts chats bot( In pure javascript, google app script) to be able to interact with users when we are offline. We wanted to know the location of the users who chat with the bot, is it possible to get the gps coordinates of the user chatting with the bot? if the user has his/her gps turned ON?
We currently ask the user for their location but we dont get accurate data, we want to grab it directly from the user's gps

Any suggestions or help will be highly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there's a way you could directly fetch their location, since that information would be protected. However, the bot can ask the users for an address and use the [Geocoding API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/start) to query for the location from the bot's back-end.

However, there does seem to be an [existing Feature Request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/128816710) for such access. You can check that link for updates on the request.